# Text Color Changes to White when select item from searchable spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using [custom](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) searchable spinner in my android application. In one of my activity, I am using two searchable spinners. one for Citys and one for area locations. On selection of 1st Spinner item, I am Changing the adapter of the 2nd spinner to show Area location of that respective City's. but when I select an item of the 2nd spinner, Text Color of the selected item of spinner changes to White. How to stop it.

I have Attached ScreenShots and Code below.

Before Selecting Any Item

[image: Before Selecting Any Item]

After Selecting Items Of Both Spinner

[image: After Selecting Items Of Both Spinner]

**Activity.java**

```
citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            if(citySpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Mumbai"))
            {
                adapterArea = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.mumbai, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapterArea.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterArea);

            }
            else  if(citySpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Delhi"))
            {
                adapterArea = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.delhi, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapterArea.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterArea);

            }
            else  if(citySpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Thane"))
            {
                adapterArea = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.thane, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapterArea.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterArea);

            }
            else  if(citySpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Select City"))
            {
                buttonAdd.setEnabled(false);
                buttonAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapterArea = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.array.blank, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapterArea.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterArea);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    areaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(areaSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Select Area")|| areaSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Select City First!"))
            {
                buttonAdd.setEnabled(false);
                buttonAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                buttonAdd.setEnabled(true);
                buttonAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

**Activity.xml**

```
    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:entries="@array/city_name"
        app:hintText="Select City"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerArea"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:hintText="Select Area"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinnerCity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinnerCity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerCity" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have Define Arrays in Resources for each City. eg.

<string-array name="mumbai">

        <item>Select Area</item>

        <item>Chandivali</item>

        <item>Andheri</item>

        <item>Malad</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="delhi">

        <item>Select Area</item>

        <item>Dwarka</item>

        <item>Chandani Chowk</item>

        <item>Alipur</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: Can you post your resource xml where you defined array?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="city_name">
        <item>Select City</item>
        <item>Mumbai</item>
        <item>Delhi</item>
        <item>Thane</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="mumbai">
        <item>Select Area</item>
        <item>Chandivali</item>
        <item>Andheri</item>
        <item>Malad</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="delhi">
        <item>Select Area</item>
        <item>Dwarka</item>
        <item>Alipur</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>`

Comment: Try replaced getApplicationContext() to getBaseContext(). Hope that helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok , Now Color is not changing but the font type is changing to system default, I want to use a custom font.
Can you help me out?

Comment: I will post answer check that.You need to change create adapter code.

Comment: Instead of creating an adapter, you may try getting adapter from your spinner. Try this: adapterArea = areaSpinner.getAdapter(); adapterArea.clear(); if...adapterArea.addAll(DataList1); else... adapterArea.notifyDataSetChanged(); Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your create adapter code.
Try this,

```
 ArrayAdapter  adapterArea=new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mumbai));
    areaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterArea);
```

Comment: Error:(105, 47): no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnItemSelectedListener>,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context) constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Object[]) is not applicable(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context) constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemSelectedListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Problem is in first argument you pass OnItemSelectedListener instance of context.

Comment: I have changed to this, now it's working, but the font type is changing to system default, I want to use a custom font.
 
 `adapterArea = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mumbai));`

Comment: Then you need to create style for custom font and set in spinner attribute.Second one you need to create custom layout and replace that ,.

Answer (score 0):

In the first spinner the layout set from the library by default but in the second spinner, you are setting it programmatically which is android made and which colors are dependable on a theme of your project so my suggestion for you to change the layout with a customized one.